# Trying to make a function to create mixed messages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am steadily learning JavaScript and I am trying to create a small page that takes in an array of words and places them in a sentence.I am having trouble making a function to get my page to run and properly show up on my page. I have already figured I am going to use math.floor(Math.random()) in a way but anything I come up with does not work! would anyone have any ideas on this subect? I have linked my github page to this question and will be presenting my html and Javascript.
https://github.com/calvinalee2006/MixedMessages

```js
const lyricButton = document.getElementById('begin_lyric').addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.className === 'text') {

  }
});


let array = [
  location = ["Miami", "New York", "California", "Texas", "Kansas"],
  drinks = ["Tequila", "Soda", "Milk", "Tea"],
  celebrity = ["Michael Jackson", "Obama", "Bennedict Cumberbatch", "elmo"],
  action = ["nod", "point", "kindly gesture", 'pop my collar']

];

lyricButton.innerHTML = `We down in ${location} going hard tonight, 
gonna throw down ${drinks} like its going out of style, 
Walk in the club fly like ${celebrity}. 
When the DJ sees me ${action} he clears the floor, 
for famous dance action that I am known for. `;
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Good Fortune!!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Create your first club hit!</h1>
  <p>Instructions:</p>
  <ol>
    <li>Select the club beat you want.</li>
    <li>The dance club generator will create the beginning of your song </li>
    <li>You can add the rest of the lyrics and create your own cub hit!!</li>
  </ol>
  <!--Button that needs to be pressed to get the result-->
  <button id="begin_lyric" class="begin_lyrics">Beginning of your song!</button>

  <!--The result-->
  <h3 id="text"></h3>


  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please see that your code example runs like you intend. At the moment you have some bugs that cause errors.

Comment: The code you posted here doesn't do anything. You have an `if` statement, but it's empty. Put the relevant code here, not at github.

Comment: `addEventListener()` doesn't return anything. So `LyricButton` is being set to `undefined`, not the `begin_lyric` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work :

```
const object = {
    location: ["Miami", "New York", "California", "Texas", "Kansas"],
    drinks: ["Tequila", "Soda", "Milk", "Tea"],
    celebrity: ["Michael Jackson", "Obama", "Bennedict Cumberbatch", "elmo"],
    action: ["nod", "point", "kindly gesture", 'pop my collar']
};

const getRandom = (array) => array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];

document.getElementById('begin_lyric').addEventListener('click', event => { document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = `We down in ${getRandom(object.location)} going hard tonight, 
gonna throw down ${getRandom(object.drinks)} like its going out of style, 
Walk in the club fly like ${getRandom(object.celebrity)}. 
When the DJ sees me ${getRandom(object.action)} he clears the floor, 
for famous dance action that I am known for. `; }
);
```

You can so see how to distinguish arrays and objects, execute code after an event dispatched, and more :)

Comment: Thank you Both for helping me out and actually understanding and reading the question.  After looking at your code sitting down and working through it, it made sense! You also told me where I was wrong and how I messed up! Your answers were helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

1. You are setting the DOM element reference in the wrong way, as action listener does not return anything and `lyricButton` is `undefined`.
2. You should use an object as key-value pair instead of saving multiple arrays in single variables. Array do not behave as you are using them right now.

The following should work for you:

```
const lyricButton = document.getElementById("begin_lyric")

lyricButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (event.target.className === "text") {}
})

let object = {
  location: ["Miami", "New York", "California", "Texas", "Kansas"],
  drinks: ["Tequila", "Soda", "Milk", "Tea"],
  celebrity: ["Michael Jackson", "Obama", "Bennedict Cumberbatch", "elmo"],
  action: ["nod", "point", "kindly gesture", "pop my collar"]
}

lyricButton.innerHTML = `We down in ${object.location} going hard 
tonight, 
gonna throw down ${object.drinks} like its going out of style, 
Walk in the club fly like ${object.celebrity}. 
When the DJ sees me ${object.action} he clears the floor, 
for famous dance action that I am known for.`
```

Comment: Thank you Both for helping me out and actually understanding and reading the question.  After looking at your code sitting down and working through it, it made sense! You also told me where I was wrong and how I messed up! Your answers were helpful!!